# Как правильно называются три открывающих угловые скобки (<<<)?

Tags: php

нужна теоретическая подсказка - как правильно называется такой способ внедрения css и/или javascript

```
$js = <<< JS
   ... your JS code here
JS;
$css = <<< CSS
   ... your CSS styles here
}
CSS;
```

Я имею в виду три открывающих угловые скобки

Comment: [heredoc-синтаксис](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: @Kromster, мне кажется не совсем корректная правка

Comment: где вы видите такой код?

Comment: @Grundy вижу его в php-коде

Comment: @buyboy вам уже ответили, что это `heredoc`. Это написано прям в мануале......екарный бабай...... Причем тут метки js и css непонятно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что JS, и CSS :-) в коде :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский по всей видимости, это код, который php потом выводит в соответствующих HTML-конструкциях посредством `echo $css;` и `echo $js;`. xD Но лично я не понимаю, где такой код может встречаться - впервые такое вижу. :)

Comment: @intro94 "впервые такое вижу" вообще-то heredoc-синтаксис много где используется, и не только в куче языков программирования. Даже в древних бородатых версиях юниксовых консолей он есть.

Comment: @PinkTux Вы меня не так поняли. :) Я знаю про heredoc-синтаксис. Я даже сам его использовал. Но я впервые вижу присваивание css- или js-кода  php-переменной. Особенно это будет странным, если моя догадка, что это для последующего его вывода, подтвердится. :)

Comment: "Но я впервые вижу присваивание css- или js-кода php-переменной" - обычное дело, не понимаю чего тут удивительного.

Comment: @Grundy предложите пожалуйста лучше!

Comment: @Kromster, а я не знаю как лучше :-) просто `<<<` еще как unsigned shift может быть или еще каким-нибудь другим оператором

Comment: @PinkTux не могу согласиться с тем, что это корректно. Но не будем об этом. Этот холивар не по сабжу. :)

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от того какиe вы цели преследуете.
Если вы динамически генерируете pdf файлы то такой способ приемлет,но если есть способ избежать хранения HTML и.т.д. в переменой то немедленно воспользуйтесь ею.

Comment: А как это связано с вопросом? Если "правильно" используешь, то heredoc, а если "неправильно" - как называть будем? Да, и так, к сведению: способ хранения переменных выбирает автор кода, а не вы.

Comment: Тут была озвучена heredoc.Я думаю достаточно сведения было об этом.Я думаю достаточно сведения было об этом.
Я имел ввиду следующее - Не надо смешивать PHP код с HTML и прочим.Надо их как то разделять,есть масса способов.А к вашему сведению добавлю что опять же стил выбегает автор,но существует правила хорошего тона